# Press EnterPad not work as submit button when pressed in Java NetBeans

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to use enter keypressed as submit button but is not functioning. What I mean is that whenever I am trying to hit the enter key no data is submitted to the DB. My code is below:

```
public class Signup extends javax.swing.JFrame implements KeyListener {

    @Override

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {

        // create function for key event for user registration sign up using enter keypad
        String fname = jTextField_name.getText();
        String sname = jTextField_surname.getText();
        String nil = jTextField_nin.getText();
        String loc = jTextField_location.getText();
        String pos = jTextField_pos.getText();
        String agentno = jTextField_agentno.getText();
        String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_password.getPassword());
        String hashpassword = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(30));
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

            if (verifyField()) {

                if (!checkPos(pos)) {

                    PreparedStatement ps;

                    ResultSet rs;

                    String registerUserQuery = "INSERT INTO `user`( `name`, `surname`, `nin`, `location`, `pos`, `agent_no`, `password`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    try {
                        ps = My_Connect.getconnection().prepareStatement(registerUserQuery);
                        ps.setString(1, fname);
                        ps.setString(2, sname);
                        ps.setString(3, nil);
                        ps.setString(4, loc);
                        ps.setString(5, pos);
                        ps.setString(6, agentno);
                        ps.setString(7, hashpassword);

                        if (ps.executeUpdate() != 0) {

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Account Has Been Created Suuccessully");
                        } else {

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error :Check your Information ");
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }

            }
            jButton_signup.doClick();
        }
    }

// create a function to verify the empty fields

public boolean verifyField(){

String fname = jTextField_name.getText();
String sname = jTextField_surname.getText();
String nil= jTextField_nin.getText();
String loc= jTextField_location.getText();
String pos = jTextField_pos.getText();
  String pass1 = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_password.getPassword());
String passc1 = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_confirmpassword.getPassword());


if(fname.trim().equals("") || sname.trim().equals("")||nil.trim().equals("")|| loc.trim().equals("") || pos .trim().equals("") || passc1.trim().equals(""))

{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"One or more field are Empty","Empty Field",2);

return false;

} 
// check if the two password are equals
else if(!pass1.equals(passc1))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password Doesn't Match","Confirm Password",2);

    return false;
}

// If the everything is ok
else
{

    return true;

}
}


// create a unaction to check if the entired username already exit in the database

public boolean checkPos(String pos){


    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;  

    boolean pos_exist = false;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `pos`= ? ";


    try {

        st = My_Connect.getconnection().prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(1, pos);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){

          pos_exist = true;
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This pos is already taken, Choose another one");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return pos_exist;
} 

 public boolean checkAgent(String agent){


    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;  

    boolean agent_exist = false;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `agent_no`= ? ";


    try {

        st = My_Connect.getconnection().prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(1, agent);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){

         agent_exist = true;
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This agent  is already taken, Choose another one");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return agent_exist;
} 


  public boolean checkNin(String nin){


    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;  

    boolean nin_exist = false;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `nin`= ? ";


    try {

        st = My_Connect.getconnection().prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(1, nin);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){

          nin_exist = true;
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This nin is already taken, Check you NIN ");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return nin_exist;
} 

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

/**
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
 */

/**
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
 * @throws java.lang.InstantiationException
 */

/**
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
 * @throws java.lang.InstantiationException
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException
 */

/**
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
 * @throws java.lang.InstantiationException
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException
 * @throws javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
 */
 public static void main(String args[])  throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LottoryPaymentType.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LottoryPaymentType.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LottoryPaymentType.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LottoryPaymentType.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
 try {
        //here you can put the selected theme class name in JTattoo
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel");
       // UIManager.setLookAndFeel ("com.jtattoo.plaf.aero.AeroLookAndFeel ");


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login .class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Signup().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: to what is that event added to? what does your listener look like?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) The data seems to be coming from text fields, add an `ActionListener` to each one. When the field (any with the listener attached) is focused and the user presses the enter key, the action will fire.

Comment: Don't use "-----" that causes the text to be bold. There is no reason for making all the text bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem for a few years. If I remember correct the problem was that the KeyListener work only when the object has the focus.

If you add:

```
frame.requestFocus();
```

and for the other components:

```
button.setFocusable(false);
```

But I think you are looking for: KeyBinding!